# Retrieving text from <span> tag element issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape some details from a wepage.
Specifically I am trying to retrieve a price.
Here is the relevant [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF6Gb.png)

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://glomark.lk/coconut/p/11624'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

price_div = soup.find('div', class_='price')

if price_div:
    price_span = price_div.find('span')
    if price_span:
        print(price_span)
    else:
        print("no span class") 
else:
    print("no div class")
```

This code returns the text in between the span as " ".

**Code reults**: `<span id="product-promotion-price"></span>`

**Should return**: `<span id="product-promotion-price">Rs 105.00</span>`

I have tried this with a different webpage and a user agent. There I get the text as 0.00.
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm5NW.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://scrape-sm1.github.io/site1/FLORA%20FACIAL%20TISSUES%202%20X%20160%20BOX%20-%20HOUSEHOLD%20-%20Categories%20market1super.com.html'
html = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

price_span= soup.find('span', class_='price')

if price_span:
  print(price_span)
else:
  print("no span class")
```

**Code reults:** `<span class="price">Rs.0.00</span>`

**Should return**: `<span class="price">Rs.95.00</span>`

Does anyone know why this happens. I would like some insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the webpage is sent, the field is 0. Then once the JavaScript loads and runs, it retrieves the price and updates that field. I verified this by opening DevTools and loading the page with the Network tab open, then reading the HTML sent originally. You are just loading the ram HTML, but no rendering it or executing any of the scripts like the browser would. Open the DevTools network tab, then load the page, and filter to "Fetch/XHR". You will see that the price comes from this URL:  https://glomark.lk/product-page/variation-detail/11624 (Notice that it is a POST request, otherwise it will return a 404).

Here is an example of how to get all the data that endpoint returns (the price is in here):

```py
import requests

url = "https://glomark.lk/product-page/variation-detail/11624"
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

referrer = "https://glomark.lk/coconut/p/11624"

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=None)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: I tried by adding a delay of 10s but the results are the same

Comment: I should have read better, I thought you were using something like puppeteer. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! As this do work, I am having trouble replicating this with other websites though. For an instance this webpage 'https://scrape-sm1.github.io/site1/FLORA%20FACIAL%20TISSUES%202%20X%20160%20BOX%20-%20HOUSEHOLD%20-%20Categories%20market1super.com.html' does not use a URL with such values. How can we proceed with such a webpage?

Comment: That page is actually static, and the field there does have the price you want. There are just two prices fields in the format of "<span class="price">Rs.xxx.00</span>", the first of which has no price, the second of which has the price. You're parsing out the wrong one. You can open DevTools to the elements tab and search (Ctrl/Cmd+f) for "price" to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much. You've been so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I checked the url you sent. Products are loaded with lazyload. and in the background, data is received via a request with the post method. https://glomark.lk/product-page/variation-detail/11624 here is the URL where the post and data came from. From here you can get promoprice and price very easily by parsing the json

```
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.post("https://glomark.lk/product-page/variation- 
    detail/11624", headers={"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})
>>> print(res.json().get("promoPrice"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work for this particular webpage. But for webpages that do not use such a URL how should we proceed? When I checked this webpage 'https://scrape-sm1.github.io/site1/COCONUT%20market1super.html' it did not contain such details. Do we not have a more common procedure?